# Why does a call to dateutil.parser.parse indicate november is december?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

If I run the following:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Wind10_463@Y2014_M11_D19", fuzzy=True)
```

I get this:

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 19, 0, 0)
```

Why is it saying December not November?

Comment: These "wild guess" algorithms are inherently unreliable. You should better specify the format you're passing instead.

Comment: Agreed. For the record, this was a colleague's code. I was just curious about the behaviour as I couldn't explain it myself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to fully parse the structure of your string. When `dateutil.parser.parse` is missing one of the fields, such as the month, it will fill it in with the current month, which is December.

[From the docs](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c):

> default: 
>   If given, this must be a datetime instance. Any fields missing in the parsed date will be copied from > this instance. The default value is the current date, at 00:00:00am.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Any idea why it can convert the year and day but not the month?

Comment: No idea sorry, that's just the parsing under the hood, you'd have to look at the source code. As ivan_pozdeev says in his comment above, if you can specify the format then you'll be better off in the long run.

Comment: There's a chance it isn't parsing the year correctly either of course, and it's just luck that the year is the same as the current year. EDIT: Tested it and yeah it doesn't parse the year correctly either, I changed it to 2013 but still got 2014 back in the datetime object.

Comment: Good point. I checked with another year and that comes back as 2014 still so really it's only managing the day..